# how to dynamically load the images with different sizes in view pager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, dynamic-programming, facebook-wall

> I am implementing user wall like facebook but i want to display image
>   as with original size. And I am using view pager to display images.
>   So how to display images according to screen size?
>   Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the scale types provided with `ImageView` class. How do you handle if the image is way larger than the screen, say taken from a DSLR at 3000x3000 resolution? What happens if the image is too small?

Have a look at the [documentation for ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

[image]

Comment: *So how to display images according to screen size?*  clarify this :)

Comment: just like facebook wall, i am making a user wall , in which i m using view pager to display images but when i change height of view pager to wrap content view pager gets disappear. And when i gave static value it shows the image but width fixed height. I dont want that to happen